# Confusing error when writing structure to file in C

Tags: c, struct

i'm trying to write a structure to a dat file, everything works fine but the data in the dat file turns into random characters (it's the same in other formats like txt)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Product
{
    char ProId[20];
    char ProName[30];
    float Price;
    int Quantity;
    int CatId;
    
};

int main(){
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen ("Product.dat", "w+");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opened file\n");
    }
                
    Product p1;
    strcpy(p1.ProId, "1");
    strcpy(p1.ProName, "Candy");
    p1.Price = 4.5;
    p1.Quantity = 5;
    p1.CatId = 1;
    
    fwrite(&p1, sizeof(p1), 1, f);
    fclose(f);
    
    return(0);
}
```

The data in Product.dat:

```
1 u            ÿÿÿÿCandy              Ù$@           @
```

I tried searching for this error but to no avail. Please help me, what is wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: What you're seeing is how the struct is stored in memory. If you want the output file to be readable strings and numbers, you'll need to use something like `fprintf()`.

Comment: You didn't write all bytes zero to the structure so you get some garbage too.  One thing `strncpy()` does is zero pad short data fields, but it doesn't guarantee thanks termination either.

Comment: This is the expected result. You're writing a binary file, you can't read it as text. If you write another program that reads the same structure and displays its contents, you'll see what you expect.

Comment: You should open the file in binary mode if your program will run on Windows.

Comment: Initialize p1 as follows: `Product p1 = {0};`

Comment: Warning: serialising struct data to file in this way is non-portable. If you were to transfer the saved file to another machine with different endianness, data alignment or padding, you will likely not be able to load the data from file back into a struct without data corruption.

Comment: This is not an error. When you read your file later you get the same data. You had not initialized the variable p1, so there some random bytes. But this doesn't care. If you care, you have to initialize p1.

Answer (score 0):

I compile and ran your code on my WSL2, and met the same problem, here is the hexdump:

```
00000000  31 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  e7 6a 5b 66 fd 7f 00 00  |1........j[f....|
00000010  e6 6a 5b 66 43 61 6e 64  79 00 d4 1a 18 56 00 00  |.j[fCandy....V..|
00000020  e8 32 96 dd 70 7f 00 00  80 12 d4 1a 18 56 00 00  |.2..p........V..|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 90 40  05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  |.......@........|
```

The string "Candy" is indeed copied to the struct.
I assume the reason it is polluted by some trash data is because this struct is allocated on stack.
So I made a clean up after the declaration of this struct, and here is the effect:

```
00000000  31 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |1...............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 43 61 6e 64  79 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....Candy.......|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 90 40  05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  |.......@........|
```

Here is the code I modified, note the call to `memset()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Product
{
        char ProId[20];
        char ProName[30];
        float Price;
        int Quantity;
        int CatId;

};

int main(){
        FILE *f;
        f = fopen ("Product.dat", "w+");
        if (f == NULL)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "\nError opened file\n");
        }

        struct Product p1;
        memset(&p1, 0, sizeof(p1));
        strcpy(p1.ProId, "1");
        strcpy(p1.ProName, "Candy");
        p1.Price = 4.5;
        p1.Quantity = 5;
        p1.CatId = 1;

        fwrite(&p1, sizeof(p1), 1, f);
        fclose(f);

        return(0);
}
```